# Windows 7: Disable automatic updates & antivirus updates on certain Wifi connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-update, automatic-update

**TL;DR** how do I disable automatic background updates when connected to certain WiFi network?

Most of the time I'm connected to my home WiFi, so I have both Windows 7 and Avira Antivirus updates enabled. 
Sometimes however I'm connecting to the Internet through my "mobile hotspot" (Android phone). In the latter case I have low transfer limits, so I'd like to **block updates**, both **Windows** and **Avira** when connected to the **certain network**. Is there any *free* tool which would do this for me?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You could create a [scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) which runs when connected to a specific Wi-Fi network, and that disables Windows updates temporarily. As for the antivirus, turning off its update feature might or might not be possible. Which exact version are you using? You might want to rephrase your question a little, because asking for tools might be interpreted as a software recommendation, and that's off-topic here.